# How to calculate the Energy momentum ($T_{\mu \nu}$), Electromagnetic field ($E_{\mu \nu}$) and Electromagnetic tensor ($F_{\mu \nu}$)

Tags: packages, physics, tensors

Given a RN-metric, how to calculate the Energy momentum ($T_{\mu \nu}$) , Electromagnetic field ($E_{\mu \nu}$) and Electromagnetic tensor ($F_{\mu \nu}$)? What is the appropriate GR tensor package to use ?

Answer (score 2):

The package [Riemannian Geometry & Tensor Calculus](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/) should get you started. After installing, read RGTC.nb, which will show you how to take covariant derivatives and build the tensors you would like.

Another good package is [diffgeo.m](http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/).

Comment: Is [xAct](http://www.xact.es) any good for this?